# Suitability of Question For Main Site?

Tags: discussion, scope

I would like to ask this question on the main site:

**Is there a proven method (that works 9/10) to applying a screen protector to an Android smartphone or tablet ?**

Comment: (I upvoted because you asked here to get feedback from the community, not because I think this would be a good question for the main site.)

Comment: @Kramps Thats fine.

Answer (score 2):

That'd almost certainly be closed with the "not Android-specific" reason. Android screens aren't different than the screens used for other smartphones or even other electronics.

So, no, I don't think that's a good question for this site.

Comment: Yes that right. However wouldn't you say its kind of a grey area as alot of Android Users are likely to want to know the answer (even if its not specifically android) ?

Comment: It's not even phone or screen specific, I've used the same technique to apply screen protectors to a phone as I've used to apply the sponsor's decal on a vehicle before a race, just scaled down!

Comment: @GAThrawn I kind of understand what you are saying but most people are probably not in the situation where they have had experience of doing that and then apply it in another scenario (albeit much smaller).